2D matrix from raster data
I want to rasterize a shapefile (with polygon data) and get a 2D matrix showing the spatial area. So I started with:
from pyogrio import read_dataframe
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

shapefile = read_dataframe('path to shapefile')

out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data = shapefile,
    measurements = ['NumValue'],  # column of 1
    resolution = [-1, 1],
    fill = 0
)

I cannot find a way to convert out_grid to a simple matrix. Also, I am not sure if I have to specify the CRS when converting to raster using make_geocube. Can somebody help ?
